# Is there an app with a historical archive of Twitter messages for a specific hashtag?

Tags: twitter

Is there a web application that lets me watch and search the history of a hashtag on Twitter from the last year?

The Twitter service only seems to have history of around a month.

Comment: You mean "archive", right?

Comment: Yes, spell mistake *corrected*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google now has access to all of Twitter's archive, as detailed in two blog posts by [Twitter](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/04/tweet-preservation.html)  and [Google](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/replay-it-google-search-across-twitter.html).

If you search for your hashtag and then click on the "updates" filter in the left sidebar Google searches through Tweets for your hashtag. You can then filter by date using the interactive chart at the top of the results. ([Example](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=%23twitter&aq=f&aqi=g10&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=9ab08fa4a3d6f3af&&tbs=mbl:1,mbl_hs:1262304000,mbl_he:1293839999))

It only currently seems to go back to around February of this year but as mentioned in the Twitter post:

> Google Replay currently only goes back a few months but eventually it will reach back to the very first Tweets ever created.